# Finding Value In Excel Based On Highest Value and Matching Value in Excel

Tags: excel

I have three rows in an Excel sheet that I need to get values from.  Row 1 are just set numbers, Row 2 is values, and Row 3 is another value with many having the same value.  I need to first check for the highest value in Row 3, match it with the value in Row 2, get the highest value in Row 2 first if Row 3 is the same, and then report Row 1 as the answer.

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26
4   4   2   1   5   7   4   3   1   5   3   3
```

So I want to have it output as:

```
6 10 5 7 2 1 12 11 8 3 9 4
```

I tried a few HLOOKUP values but nothing seems to be hooking.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do a horizontal sort with the primary sort on row 3 then a secondary on row 2 and then row 1 will be in the order you want.

Comment: @ScottCraner  I'm amazed that you were able to interpret the requirements.

Comment: I'm trying to keep the integrity of the rows.  I don't need the row itself changed I need to output this into a descending column afterwards on a separate page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a formula answer use this array formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$L$1,MATCH(LARGE(($A$3:$L$3*10000)+$A$2:$L$2,COLUMN(A:A)),($A$3:$L$3*10000)+$A$2:$L$2,0))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

So enter the formula in the first cell, hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter Then drag/Copy across the number of columns desired.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the answer.  Thanks for understanding, I honestly couldn't think how to explain this which I think hurt my chances of finding it on Google.  Works like a charm!